# Input Loops Not Using Ints

Tags: java, loops

I have been working on this and searching for so long. I am very new (as in a week) to this and I can not seem to figure out how to loop (do/while or etc..) the month or color input. I have only been able to find loop help regarding int. I have read that I may have to convert to an int. Sorry if this question is too vague. It is for a class and I am trying to learn, so if you wouldn't mind explaining as well, in simple terms.

```
package FortuneTeller;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FortuneTeller {

    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println("Hello human. What is your first name?");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("And your last?");
        String name2 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println(name + " "+ name2 + "? Interesting. What is your age?");
        int age = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What number earth month were you born in?");
        int month;
        **month = input.nextInt();**
        switch (month) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("January");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("February");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("March");
                break;
            case 4: 
                System.out.println("April");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("May");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("June");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("July");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("August");
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("September");
                break;
            case 10:
                System.out.println("October");
                break;
            case 11:
                System.out.println("November");
                break;
            case 12:
                System.out.println("December");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("This is no Earth month. What EARTH month were you born in?");
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("Favorite ROYGBIV color. Type \"Help\" if you are unsure of the reference.");
        String color;
        **color = input.next();**
        switch (color.toLowerCase()) {
                case "red":
                System.out.println("What is your number of siblings?");
                break;
            case "orange":
                System.out.println("What is your number of siblings?");
                break;
            case "yellow":
                System.out.println("What is your number of siblings?");
                break;
            case "green":
                System.out.println("What is your number of siblings?");
                break;
            case "blue":
                System.out.println("What is your number of siblings?");
                break;
            case "indigo":
                System.out.println("What is your number of siblings?");
                break;
            case "violet":
                System.out.println("What is your number of siblings?");
                break;
            case "help":
                System.out.println("ROYGBIV consist of Red. Orange. Yellow. Green. Blue. Indigo. Violet." +"\n"
                + "What is your favorite ROYGBIV color?");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("This is an invalid color. Type \"Help\" if you are unsure of the reference. "); 
        }

        int siblings = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Thank you!" + "\n" 
            + name + name2 );

        if (age %2==0) {
            System.out.println("You will hit the lottery in the next 10 years.");
        } else; {
            System.out.println("You will come into a high paying, enjoyable job in the next 5 years.");
        }

        if (siblings ==1) {
            System.out.println("You will live in a new place every 5 years.");
        }

        if (siblings ==2) {
            System.out.println("You will live in your home town and make it a better place with your resources.");
        }

        if (siblings ==3) {
            System.out.println("You and your three siblings will live successfully in a major city abroad.");
        }

        if (siblings >4) {
            System.out.println("You will start a comunie with all of your family in a beautiful remote place.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("An unexspected surprise will land you in a beautiful forign city with everything you need.");
        }

        switch (color) {
            case "Red" :
                System.out.println("You will travel by car");
                break;
            case "Orange" :
                System.out.println("You will travel by hot air balloon.");
                break;
            case "Yellow" :
                System.out.println("You will travel by plane");
                break;
            case "Green" :
                System.out.println("You will travel by train");
                break;
            case "Blue" :
                System.out.println("You will travel by boat");
                break;
            case "Indigo" :
                System.out.println("You will travel by submarine");
                break;
            case "Violet" :
                System.out.println("You will travel by big rig");
        }

        if ((month ==1) || ( month ==2) || (month ==3) || (month==4)) {
            System.out.println("Consider taking more time to read");
        } else if ((month ==5) || (month ==6) || (month ==7) || (month ==8)) {
            System.out.println("Consider taking on a mechanical hobby");
        } else if ((month ==9) || (month ==10) || (month ==11) || (month ==12)) {
            System.out.println("Consider taking on an artistic hobby");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Continue to attract atoms. The culmination will be worth wile.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't worked with Java in *years*, so I'm not what's a syntax error these days, but `} else; {` looks off, as does `**month = input.nextInt();**` and ` **color = input.next();**` (might just be for highlighting, not sure)

Comment: Yeah, those are just to highlight the sections I'm trying to loop.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Antonio, you’ve provided an awful lot of code there. Can you edit to a [mcve] and point out exactly what has gone wrong? I’m not sure exactly what/why you’re trying to use a loop for.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, your clarification "loop each part, in case of invalid input" makes it much clearer what you're asking.  You'll want something like:

```
// declare & init a boolean variable "monthIsValid" to false
while (!monthIsValid) {
    // ...the code to ask for the month and print it, like you already have
    }
```

except that inside the loop you'll want to set `monthIsValid` to `true` in each of the 12 cases.  (Well that's very repetitive; you can be 'sneaky' and set `monthIsValid` to `true` right before you ask for it, and then only in the `default`/invalid case do you go back and set it to `false`.)

Understand, that this program assignment is a bit drudgy.  In particular, I practically *never* need a `switch` statement; I feel that `if`-`else`-`if` would be more appropriate for a learner (since it's a basic construct that'll server you many many times).  Some people have suggested that once you know arrays, there are much easier ways to do this problem (so don't feel that programming is inherently repetitious).  Also, in my teaching-Java, I focus on having separate functions (so I might ask for a separate function `colorMessage` which takes in a string and returns a string, or returns a sentinel-value if there is no appropriate message).  That would decompose this big rambling problem into nicer, self-contained chunks.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I really appreciate the time and explanations. I kind of understand, but cant figure out how to place that into my code. Its quite alright though. I feel like it was maybe a dumb question. I feel as if I don't really know how to ask the question.  

Thank you for your time again.